# Calling a method in a Javascript Constructor and Accessing Its Variables

Tags: javascript, prototype, constructor, methods

I am trying to call a method from the constructor of my javascript constructor, is this possible and if so, I can't seem to get it working, any insight would be great! Thanks!

```
function ValidateFields(pFormID){
    var aForm = document.getElementById(pFormID);
    this.errArray = new Array();//error tracker
    this.CreateErrorList();
}
/*
 * CreateErrorList()
 * Creates a list of errors:
 *   <ul id="form-errors">
 *    <li>
 *     You must provide an email.
 *    </li>
 *   </ul>
 * returns nothing
 */
 ValidateFields.prototype.CreateErrorList = function(formstatid){
     console.log("Create Error List");
 }
```

I got it to work with what is above, but I can't seem to access the 'errArray' variable in CreateErrorList function.

Comment: pythonists who land here: initializing an object in javascript has to be done with the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, when your constructor function executes, the `this` value has already the `[[Prototype]]` internal property pointing to the `ValidateFields.prototype` object.

Now, by looking at the your edit, the `errArray` variable is not available in the scope of the  `CreateErrorList` method, since it is bound only to the scope of the constructor itself.

If you need to keep this variable *private* and only allow the `CreateErrorList` method to access it, you can define it as a *privileged method*, within the constructor:

```
function ValidateFields(pFormID){
  var aForm = document.getElementById(pFormID);
  var errArray = [];

  this.CreateErrorList = function (formstatid){
    // errArray is available here
  };
  //...
  this.CreateErrorList();
}
```

Note that the method, since it's bound to `this`, will not be *shared* and it will exist physically on all object instances of `ValidateFields`.

Another option, if you don't mind to have the `errArray` variable, as a *public* property of your object instances, you just have to assign it to the `this` object:

```
//..
this.errArray = [];
//..
```

More info:

- [Private Members in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html)
- [Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html)

Comment: After some more research I found out that the 'errarray' must have the keywork this in front of it so that it may be available to other methods. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 7):

**Solution:**

```
function ValidateFields(pFormID){
    console.log("ValidateFields Instantiated");
    var aForm = document.getElementById(pFormID);
    this.errArray = new Array();//error tracker
    this.CreateErrorList(); //calling a constructors method
}

ValidateFields.prototype.CreateErrorList = function(){
   console.log("Create Error List");
   console.log(this.errArray); //this is how to access the constructors variable
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who might have a question like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an object of `ValidateFields` somewhere?

**Edit**: You need to prepend `this` whenever referring to a function's public properties.

Updated the code here:
http://jsbin.com/afiru/edit

Comment: Yes...I am http://jsbin.com/afiru/2/edit

Although, I should rephrase my question, I finally got it to work the way it is above but for some reason I can't access the 'errArray' variable in CreateErrorList